# Avoid list reset inside a loop

Tags: java, list

I am trying to create a list of objects inside a loop.
But when I assign items to the list, the list gets reset every iteration.

```
List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
People people = new People();

public  void test() {
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        people.name = "name "+i;
        people.age = "age "+i;
    
        peopleList .add(people);
        
    }
}
```

After executing the loop, the peopleList value is the same.

I am expecting to have a list(peopleList) containing 2 items.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your people within the loop. At the moment you are just updating the same object every time.

```
List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();

public void test() {
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
     People people = new People();
     people.name = "name "+i;
     people.age = "age "+i;
    
     peopleList.add(people);
        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is you are adding the same people object multiple times.
Since people is a reference data type, when you add to the list, a new object is not added.

Instead, create a new object inside the loop

```java
List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();

public void test() {
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        People people = new People();
        people.name = "name "+i;
        people.age = "age "+i;
        peopleList.add(people);
    }
}
```

Now this should work

You can refer to this article https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-5/4-objects-and-references if you want to learn more about primitive and reference data types and objects in java.